# Typescript type guard union type

Tags: typescript

I have the following type guard:

```
enum X {
    A = "1"
}

const isNullableX = (value: any): value is X | null => false

let foo: string | null = ''

if (isNullableX(foo)) {
  console.log(foo)
}
```

I would expect the type of `foo` in the last `console.log` to be `X | null` but instead, it's only `X`. Can someone explain to me how this works? If I change the declaration of `foo` to `let foo: unknown = ''` then the type in the `console.log` is inferred correctly.

Here's an example to play with: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAGlDeAoKKoEEoF4oCICMOiAvoogMYD2IAzgC5QCW1AcmADZsCGARm8HNgAUAN05swwAFxROIAJ4BKaaPHBG1WFAA+UcBywA+KADMx1YKT71jFCtLoAnBiADm23ezZYoAch+kGYyhBJlYOHj4YQRsKBQUEZChKGgo+ADo2Chdo2wViIA)

Comment: Assuming the question is "how does this work", the answer is that [user defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), like all type guards, can only serve to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of a value; it does not *widen* things.  The statement `let foo: string | null = ""` is already an [narrowing assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) to just `string`.  So when using `X | null` to narrow `string`, you get `X`.

Comment: Does that fully address the question? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that type guards works only by narrowing. It makes more sense now, thanks.

Comment: But now I have another doubt, how would you turn a `string | null` into a `Enum | null` without an explicit type cast? Is there a way to do it using type guards? (I've updated the question with another example)

Comment: Are you changing the scope of the question now? The new example runs afoul of a known bug at [ms/TS#31156](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31156) so I'm not sure how to proceed except to work around it, say with a type assertion (the thing you're calling a "cast" is an "assertion"; the term "cast" is fairly ambiguous and often implies runtime coercion or reflection which TS doesn't have... avoiding the word "cast" in TS is probably for the best)

Comment: Right now I'd say you should pick either the top question or the bottom question and get rid of the other one (so that the question is only about one thing).  Let me know when it stabilizes and maybe I'll come back to answer.

Comment: You're right, I'll go only with the first question then. Thanks also for the "assertion" vs "cast" clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript uses [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of an expression to be more specific.  For example, when you [assign a value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) to a variable of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), it will narrow the type of the variable to just those union members which work for that value, at least until the next assignment.  So for this:

```
let foo: string | null = ''    
foo // string
```

The compiler has already narrowed `foo` from `string | null` to just `string`.  The compiler knows that `foo` is not `null` after that assignment.  (If you change this to `let foo = Math.random()<0.5 ? '' : null` then the assignment won't narrow and things might behave as you expect later.)

---

Control flow analysis will either *narrow* the apparent type of an expression, or *reset* the type back to the annotated or original type.  What you can't realistically do is arbitrarily *widen* a type, or *mutate* a type to something unrelated.

When you call a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like

```
const isNullableX = (value: any): value is X | null => false
```

it will, depending on the output, *narrow* the type of its input.  In your call here:

```
if (isNullableX(foo)) {
  foo // X
}
```

you are narrowing `foo` from `string` to something assignable to `X | null`.  The only plausible result here is `X`, since `null` is not assignable to `string`.  And so `foo` is narrowed to `X`.  If you were expecting `foo` to change from `string` to `X | null`, that can't happen because it's sort of an arbitrary mutation (I suppose it could be a reset-followed-by-a-narrowing, but there's no resetting because there's no reassignment).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAGlDeAoKUCCUC8UBEBGbiAvoogMYD2IAzgC5QCWVAcmADasCGARq8HFgAoAbh1ZhgALigcQATwCUUkWOAMqsKAB8o4dpgB8UAGaiqwErzpHy5KbQBO9EAHMtOtq0xQA5N5LXyKAB6IKgHJ2cSeiMoAUYWdm5eGAEA+XkEZGMbYNCYIhIgA)

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
enum X {
    A = "1"
}

function assertIsTrue(condition: unknown): asserts condition is boolean {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error("Not True!");
  }
}

const isNullableX = (value: any): value is X | null => false

let foo = '' as string | null;

assertIsTrue(isNullableX(foo));

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: This way the type of `foo` become `string | null`, the enum is ignored.

Comment: Anyway I've updated the example by removing the assertion, it's unnecessary for the problem

Comment: oopsie... my bad! I read it as `string | null`.